# I'm just going to throw this out there, but Google indexes Stack Overflow really quickly

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google, indexing

For example, I [posted a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378978/using-the-netbeans-gui-editor-how-can-i-create-a-jtextfield-or-jformattedtext-fi) after using Google to try to find an answer. I then turned back to Google and did a search for [`netbeans validate jtextfield against regex`](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&fkt=637&fsdt=8253&q=netbeans+validate+jtextfield+against+regex&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=d9ca629f83f82f8a) and it was already the first result! Similar searches also put my question on the first page, usually in the top 5!

This is insanity. Did I get lucky and post just before an indexing? Is the popularity of SO leading to Google indexing extremely frequently? Or is Jeff using some kind of crazy SEO?

Comment: Well, I guess that's why Google has become a verb...

Comment: Just proves how valuable SO has become. :-)

Answer (score 22):

Yup. As soon as I read a question, it goes straight into the index...

(That's my unfair advantage - no-one else can search for a question until I've read it.)

Comment: Is that your new job at Google; fact-checking *all* the new pages found by the search spiders?

Comment: @rcartaino: That's just what I do while I'm waiting for my builds to finish...

Comment: Like so: http://trusko.es/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/compiling.png

Comment: @rlb.usa: original source: http://xkcd.com/303/

Answer (score 14):

A recent one: [Podcast #66](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/)

> It’s incredible how aggressive
> Google’s indexing of our site is; it
> regularly pulls down a gigabyte of
> compressed text from us per day, and
> it wants to do even more. One of the
> primary motivators for adding a second
> server is to reduce the traffic load
> enough so that we can “unleash” google
> via webmaster tools.

Comment: Ah. I haven't listened to 66 yet. I should do that, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It has been well documented in the past that Google absolutely loves indexing StackOverflow.

Comment: Really? I only saw one blog post by Jeff. Could you provide links? I would love to read more.

Comment: A cursory search: Podcast 010, 011, 012, 065 talks about google indexing SO. Search http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Astackoverflow.fogbugz.com+google+spider&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=d9ca629f83f82f8a , then do a quick text search on those pages for mentions of `google` or `spider`.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest podcast (66) jeff mentions that google is indexing SO insanely. They're thinking about adding another server, so google can index SO even more.