# How did stackoverflow get its success? (SEO question)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How is stack overflow optimized for Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/how-is-stack-overflow-optimized-for-google)
>   [SEO in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stackoverflow)

I joined stackoverflow.com because I kept seeing relatively good question/responses showing up in Google searches.

What I am asking, is does anyone know/remember how **they** *first* got into this site (at the start). Was it google, advertisement, announcement at a conference, friend referral?

*people have to find it first*

> **How did stackoverflow.com get enough good quality content to draw quality question posters to the site?** Did they ask alot of questions themselves? If it didn't create much content, how was the site's functionality good enough to draw question posters to it?

**This site is a true Whitehat SEO** site, IMO. I am just wondering what tricks they used to become popular so fast. (Besides so many posts that they have now)

Comment: Good question, but probably belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I think the creators already had a critical mass of programmers following their blogs to make it work.

Comment: Somewhat ironic that this is coming up [now](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/12721357573857280#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site founders already had large audiences from their programming blogs.  You can go back to the [old podcast episodes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-1/) to hear how they originally promoted the site to get a huge number of people interested even before it launched.