# Does Google work for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I'm just going to throw this out there, but Google indexes Stack Overflow really quickly…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20171/im-just-going-to-throw-this-out-there-but-google-indexes-stack-overflow-really)
>   [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines)

Some minutes ago (less than 10) I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175907/update-a-select-list-in-a-partial-view) on Stack Overflow.

Then, waiting for an answer I have tried to do a Google search about the same argument and like magic the first link returned by Google search was my post on Stack Overflow!

How could this be possible? With the frequency that questions and answers are posted on Stack Overflow does Google continuously index the Stack Overflow site?

[image]

Comment: Voted to move to meta.

Comment: While I can understand that probably the question shoul be moved to meta, I can't really understand the downvote...

Comment: old school podcast info. they designed the site to work with Google as the entry point.

Comment: +1 upvoted.  Reads to me like "how does this internet technology work?" so i think its appropriate

Comment: I didn't downvote on this, btw. That was someone else.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20171/im-just-going-to-throw-this-out-there-but-google-indexes-stack-overflow-really

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably sending updates to google.  Take a look at google admin tools I believe.

Comment: It also has to be a pretty big site, and seen as frequently updated.

Answer (score 2):

Posts to my blog show up in 10 minutes or less on average - Wordpress pings various services and my blog doesn't even generate that much traffic. SO is huge, constantly updating  and frequently back linked. Stands to reason it'd be indexed fast.