# How questions on Stack Overflow are indexed on Google as soon as they are posted?

Tags: discussion, search, google, indexing, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I'm just going to throw this out there, but Google indexes Stack Overflow really quickly…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20171/im-just-going-to-throw-this-out-there-but-google-indexes-stack-overflow-really)
>   [SEO in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stackoverflow)

I have noticed one thing many times, as soon as we post contents on stack overflow and search something relevant to our question, Google search results contains those posts.

How does this real time indexing takes place in Stack Overflow?

Technically how can we achieve this?

Comment: Sites with high authority have a much higher crawl rate, therefore new posts on the site are pushed into the index much quicker

Comment: Yup, I came to know that Google is crawling Stack 10 times per second. Amazing ------------http://www.businessinsider.com/google-stackoverflow-2011-3

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by creating a great site that gets tons of traffic and has lots of fresh, interesting, original content.  :)

Comment: +1 for the fantastic tip

Comment: I should have thought of that earlier, when I was planning on creating crappy sites ;-)

Comment: Lots of fresh content is the *really* important thing here, although the others certainly help.

Comment: @Lukas you would not BELIEVE the number of people who tell me they need "help with SEO" when what they really need is someone to redo their crappy site from the ground up.

Comment: @Scott: I DO believe you!

Answer (score 1):

A [sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=156184&from=40318&rd=1) that is well tuned and read often by google may have something to do with this...  A Sitemap can contrain a list of new/changes pages to help google on it's way.